# Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ is equal to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$.

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $\mathbb{N} = \{1,2,3,4,\dots \}$ and define the sets $A_k \subset \mathbb{N}$ by 
>   $$
> A_k = \{k,2k,3k,\dots \}
> $$
>   for $k = 1,2,\dots$. We denote by $\mathcal{H}$ the collection $\{A_1, A_2, \dots \} \cup \emptyset$.
>
> Show that $\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ (the sigma-algebra generated by $\mathcal{H}$) is equal to $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ (the power set of $\mathbb{N}$).

We know that $A_i^c \in \sigma(\mathcal{P})$ and finite intersections are again in the sigma-algebra. I tried to construct singletons out of these operations because if they are in $\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ then could construct the powerset by taking unions (I think) but I couldn't do it. I also found out that $A_i \cap A_j = A_{lcm(i,j)} \in \mathcal{H}$. So that $\mathcal{H}$ is stable under finite intersections. But now I'm stuck.

Comment: Hint: Can you show the singleton $\{47\}$ is in $\sigma(\mathcal H)$?

Comment: Is it true because $47$ is a prime number the set $\{47 \}$ is only in $A_1$ and $A_{47}$. So that for example with $2$, because it is prime as well, we can construct $\{2 \} = A_2 \cap (\cup_{3}^{\infty} A_i)$?

Comment: Next, how about $\{k\}$ for composite $k$?

Comment: I think we can extend this technique to composite numbers as well. $\{6\}\in A_6 = A_2 \cap A_3$. But isn't it true that $\{6\} = A_6 \cap (\cup_{i=7}^{\infty} A_i)$. If that's true we constructed the singletons and we're done!

Comment: Perhaps you want $\{6\} = A_6 \setminus (\cup_{i=7}^{\infty} A_i)$.

Comment: Oh, of course. I made that mistake before as well. But if we have the singletons we can just take (countable) unions and construct the power set. Thank you so much for helping me and guiding me through!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question:

We can construct the singletons as follows: 
$$
\{i\} = A_i \backslash \cup_{t = i+1}^{\infty}A_t, \quad \forall i \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Now that we know $\sigma(\mathcal{H})$ contains all the singletons and therefore we know that this sigma-algebra is equal to the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$, because we can construct it by taking unions of singletons.